# Does a time-independent charge distribution necessarily imply an electrostatic situation?

Tags: electromagnetism

If it is specified that a charge distribution $\rho (\textbf{r},t)$ is time-independent, $\rho (\textbf{r},t) = \rho (\textbf{r})$, then it follows from continuity that $\nabla \cdot \textbf{j}(\textbf{r}, t) = 0.$

Now the definition of an electrostatic situation is one in which the $\textbf{E}$ and $\textbf{B}$ fields decouple; that is, Gauss's and Faraday's Laws must reduce to
$$\nabla \cdot \textbf{E} = \rho (\textbf{r})/\epsilon_0 \quad({\rm A})$$
$$\nabla \times \textbf{E} = \textbf{0},\quad({\rm B})$$
which is to say that we need $\frac{\partial \textbf{B}}{\partial t} = \textbf{0}$. This is in turn only true (Ampere-Maxwell Law) if (1) $\frac{\partial \textbf{E}}{\partial t} = \textbf{0}$ and (2) $\textbf{j}(\textbf{r}, t)=\textbf{j}(\textbf{r})$. Now (1) presupposes that (A) and (B) hold, although given the circularity I'm sure there's some uniqueness theorem I can appeal to (Helmholtz or the like). It's (2) that I'm not sure about. In particular, the conditions I give in the first paragraph only let us conclude that $\nabla \cdot \textbf{j}(\textbf{r}, t) = 0.$ Thus my question boils down to, does $\nabla \cdot \textbf{j}(\textbf{r}, t) = 0$ imply that $\textbf{j}(\textbf{r}, t)=\textbf{j}(\textbf{r})$?

Note that I am taking an isolated system in which $\rho (\textbf{r},t) = \rho (\textbf{r})$ is true for all $t$, so there are no free EM fields (if (2) is true).

Comment: Taking Electrostatics to mean time independence of E and B. If you have a time independant charge distribution, that is the charge density remains constant, this does not imply that E and B are time invariant. E.g a current loop that oscillates, EM waves are created but the charge density is constant in all points in space ( it obviously begs the question, how does such a current loop change its current). You can also technicaly have a situation  where $\vec{J}$ , $\rho$ are time invariant   and have a  non static  EM field, this is where the homogenous solution of the EM field comes into play

Comment: (1) presupposes that (B) holds, not that (A) holds. The EM field can exist independantly on charges and such a homogenous solution could in theory exist that does not effect the charge density .

Comment: This is also a different question than "does the electrostatic condition mean the charge  density is Time invariant", the answer to that question is yes, if you have an electrostatic situation, then first of all, B has to be time.invariant, from the retarded potentials we can see this is only the case if A is time invariant, from this we can see that for E to be time invariant, the scalar potential v must be time independant which means rho must also be time independant. But I could imagine a situation which could allow for the homogenous solution to cancel with the fields generated by time

Comment: -dependant sources , to make the total E ,B field time invariant. So aslong as the homogenous  solution is zero, then rho and J will be time invariant given E and B are

Comment: Would like to further  clarify "Note that I am taking an isolated system in which ρ(r,t)=ρ(r) is true for all t, so there are no free EM fields (if (2) is true)." Is incorrect, 2 is true does NOT imply this

Answer (score 6):

2 questions seem to be asked here:

**(1)Does a Time independant charge distribution  imply electrostatics?**

No, Take a circular ring with osscilating current. This produces EM waves with a time independant charge distribution.

Well what if we also set $\vec{J}$ to be time independant?

Still no, $\vec{J}$ and $\rho$ being time independant does not imply $\frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t},\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}$ to be zero, this is because the EM field is not uniquely determined by the location and values of charge and currents, for example the homogenous wave equation

**(2)Does the electrostatic condition imply a time independant charge distribution**

Yes, setting $\frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t},\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}$ to be zero by force;

This imposes certain conditions onto $\rho$ and $\vec{J}$

**Gauss law:**
$$\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$
$$\nabla \cdot \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{\epsilon_0 }\frac{\partial \rho }{\partial t}$$
$$\frac{\partial \rho }{\partial t} = 0$$

**Amperes law:**

$$\nabla ×  \vec{B} = \mu_0 \vec{J} + \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}$$

$$\nabla ×  \vec{B} = \mu_0 \vec{J} $$

$$\nabla ×  \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} = \mu_0 \frac{\partial \vec{J}}{\partial t} $$

$$\frac{\partial \vec{J}}{\partial t} = 0$$

This means that when we find the fields in the electrostatic condition, both the charge density and current density are time invariant. Checking our answer, the solution to maxwells equations in this form is coulombs law and biot savart, when the charge density and current density(divergenceless) are time invariant, the fields are also time invariant.

Comment: Read my edit; the previous answer was wrong as I did not prove that inputs into coulombs law and biot savart must be time independant, Only that the fields satisfy these laws( which don't need to be time independant)

Comment: Is it possible to comment on my question in the comment to the other answer? I’m happy to accept your answer in that case.

Comment: If I understand your comment,   the electrostatic condition is NOT equivelant to saying the sources are time independant. The latter is implied by the first, but is not equivelant since you can have time independent sources with time dependant fields

Comment: But I specify that the sources have never been moving in an isolated system, so surely the dependent fields cannot exist?

Comment: Like I said before, the electromagnetic field is an independant entity and is not uniquely determined by charges and currents, if charges did not exist, theoretically  there could be "background " solutions, that are non zero.

Comment: What does setting $\rho = 0, \vec{J}  = 0$ mean? Well this means, "what are the EM fields of a universe with no charges and currents?" Doing so gets you two equations $$\nabla^2 \vec{E} = \mu_0\epsilon_0 \frac{\partial^2 \vec{E}}{\partial t^2}$$ $$\nabla^2 \vec{B} = \mu_0\epsilon_0 \frac{\partial^2 \vec{B}}{\partial t^2}$$ (These equations are also restricted by some other ways) The solution to these equations does not have to be zero, but can be e.g a sine wave.

Comment: How do we we know which solution is correct? There are infinitely many solutions. This I believe is an initial value problem. Take y' = 1, the solution is y = x + c, how do we determine the value of c? By substituting an initial condition, how do we obtain this initial condition? In terms of our wave equation, we don't. To my knowledge, we can never know the true value of this initial condition since that would require some intrinsic knowledge about the universe. It could.be that this solution is zero, however maxwells equations themselfs do not require it to be so.

Comment: When solving the fields with sources, this background solution can be added, and will still satisfy maxwells equations.

Comment: But surely my requirement that the system be isolated and that the sources have never moved is the initial condition (at time minus infinity) which rules out such free dynamical fields?

Comment: No, like I said, this solution is independant of charges and currents.

Comment: The fact that maxwells equations imply the existence of fields without the need for charges, imply that the EM field is an independant entity existing independant of charges and we should instead think of charges as interacting with the EM field rather than create it. The EM field Has its own degrees of freedom, that are independant of the state of charges

Comment: Can you provide a source for this last statement? I find it hard to believe that the founders of classical electromagnetism would have suggested that an EM field could exist in an isolated universe with no charge or current. Surely, as I suspect, the field must have radiated from some charge somewhere?

Comment: Source: maxwells equations

Answer (score 3):

The questions hinges on what you mean by an "isolated system."  Because changing $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ fields are sources for one-another, it is easy to have solutions of Maxwell's Equations with time-independent $\rho$ and $\vec{J}$ but time-dependent fields.  In fact, it is straightforward to set $\rho=0$ and $\vec{J}=0$ and still have dynamical $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ fields.  That's just the situation in which there are propagating plane electromagnetic waves but no sources.

If you want to rule out the existence of such waves by saying you have an "isolated system," then such solutions do not exist.  However, saying you have an isolated system is not a mathematical statement of precisely what conditions you want to impose.  It will turn out that if you seek to enforce that there are no external propagating electromagnetic waves, then whatever mathematical conditions you impose to enforce that condition will necessarily be equivalent to having only time-independent sources $\rho$ and $\vec{J}$.

If you do not insist that there are no propagating waves, then it is no problem to have a system of currents for which $\rho$ is constant and $\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{J}=0$ without the behavior being time-independent.  Any magnetostatic current distribution $\vec{J}(\vec{x},t)=\vec{J}(\vec{x},0)$ can be modified with a time-dependent modulation givng it the overall form, $\vec{J}(\vec{x},t)=\vec{J}(\vec{x},0)f(t)$.  This clearly still satisfies $\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{J}=0$, since the spatial derivatives are all simply scaled by $f(t)$. Hence, by the local charge conservation equation, the system still has no charge accumulation, or $\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}=0$. In this case, the magnetic field is clearly going to vary with time, simply because $\vec{J}$ does, and thus there will also be an electric field generated by Faraday induction.  These $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ fields will, in fact, combine to produce outgoing radiation of energy, just as in the cases described above.

Comment: I see. In terms of an equivalent condition to the time derivatives of the fields being zero, is saying that the charge and current sources must both be time-independent the best/most general thing we can say? I guess that's the crux of my question, since what we can observe in a given situation are typically the sources.